# Calculating Percentage of no new rows in database

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a script to see if there is any activity on the PC's we manage (i've created a program in C# which checks for activity every 5 minutes). The database looks like this:

**server:**

```
readip, time(datetime), user, computeruse (int, 0=no 1=yes), ID
```

I've already got a cronjob running for creating a percentage of computeruse after each day. But if the computer of the client is off this won't be count with it.

Is there any way to check if there are NO new row's added to the database for a certain time?

My code is:

```
'$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' AND    serverip<='$ipto' AND DATE(time) = CURDATE() GROUP BY serverip ORDER BY time");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $serverip = $row2['serverip'];

    $queryfornumrowsno = mysql_query("SELECT * From server WHERE serverip = '$serverip'") or die(mysql_error());
    $numrowstotal = mysql_num_rows($queryfornumrowsno) . ' ';

    $queryfornumrowsyes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server WHERE serverip = '$serverip' AND computeruse = 'Yes'");
    $numrowsyes = mysql_num_rows($queryfornumrowsyes);

    $percentage = $numrowsyes * 100 / $numrowstotal;
    $percentage = round($percentage);
    $percentagetotal[] = $percentage;



    $datenow = $row2['time'];


}
$totaalPercentage = 0;
foreach( $percentagetotal as $totaal )
{
    $totaalPercentage += $totaal;
}

$percentagecount = count($percentagetotal);


if($percentagecount == "0"){
    $totaal = "0";
}
else{
    $totaal =  $totaalPercentage / $percentagecount;
}
echo $datenow . ' @ ' . $totaal . '% van ' . $lokaal . '<br />'; 
if($datenow){


}
```

Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language.

**Solution:**

```
include 'connect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM iprange");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$ipfrom = $row['iprangefrom'];
$lokaal = $row['lokaal'];
$ipto = $row['iprangeto'];
$ipfrom = ip2long($ipfrom);
$ipto = ip2long($ipto);
$listpc = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' AND            serverip<='$ipto' AND DATE(time) = CURDATE() AND computeruse = 'Yes'");
$countpc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' AND serverip<='$ipto' AND DATE(time) = CURDATE() GROUP BY serverip ORDER BY time") or die(mysql_error());
$countpcrows = mysql_num_rows($countpc);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $listpc = $listpc + 1;

    }

echo $countpcrows . ' ' . $listpc . '<br />';
$percentage = $listpc / 84 * 100 / $countpcrows;
    //84 = 5 minutes.
echo round($percentage) . '%';
}
```

Comment: Add a timestamp to the col structure and compare it with PHP time(). Without showing what you have tried, it's hard to guess how to put this into your context.

Comment: Your English is fine, but I still don't understand the problem :-(

Comment: No new rows for a given user or machine or just date? Assuming you have a list of all computers and you are getting a percentage of time used for a day, just have the default be 0%, so no results means it will be 0.

Comment: Is that 'What percentage of rows in my table are not new?'

Comment: Can you show us an example query or at least example output of query you are using? I think I have an idea what you are after, but it makes a difference if you are using aggregate functions or not.

Comment: @Anthony The c# program insert's a new row each 5 minutes, but when the PC is off, the program can't send any data. So, for instance, if the PC is off from 10:00 to 11:00 I want that to count as "computeruse = 0".

Comment: @Anthony I'll update my question with the code

Comment: Have one sub query to get the list of servers (or better, use a table that just lists the servers), and LEFT JOIN that to another sub query that counts the number of rows for each server in the last X minutes. When there is no match (ie, check for NULL in the WHERE clause) then that is a server with no activity in the last X minutes.

Comment: @Kickstart The problem with that is that if one computer boots up at 10:00 and another at 10:02 the last one will not be seen by numrows...

Comment: There is a flaw in this design. It assumes that if there are 3 rows, then I used the machine for 3%. Percentage should be `number of rows / number of possible rows`, so for 5 minute increments over a 1 hour span, it would be ` number of rows / 12 `

Comment: $lokaal is the max posible row's (all the row's within the same IP, no matter computeractivity)

Comment: Can you post a few rows of data with an example of what you want output for a particular time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of servers with no activity in the last 10 minutes:-

```
SELECT a.serverip
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT serverip 
    FROM server 
    WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' 
    AND   serverip<='$ipto' 
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT serverip 
    FROM server 
    WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' 
    AND   serverip<='$ipto' 
    AND time > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 MINUTE) 
) b
ON a.serverip = b.serverip
WHERE b.serverip IS NULL
```

First sub query gets the list of servers in the range you are interested in. The 2nd gets the servers with any activity in the last 10 minutes. The LEFT JOIN will get a combination of the 2, including those servers with no activity in the last 10 minutes. The WHERE clause will then exclude all those except those with any activity in the last 10 minutes.

Based on this you should be able to calculate a percentage. Do you want the percentage as the number of all servers, or just those in the range you are interested in?

Assuming as a percentage of all servers in the range you are interested in:-

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT a.serverip) / c.all_server) * 100 AS percentage_not_used
FROM server a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS all_server
    FROM server
    WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' 
    AND   serverip <='$ipto' 
) c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT serverip 
    FROM server 
    WHERE serverip >='$ipfrom' 
    AND   serverip<='$ipto' 
    AND time > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 MINUTE) 
) b
ON a.serverip = b.serverip
WHERE a.serverip >='$ipfrom' 
AND   a.serverip <='$ipto' 
AND   b.serverip IS NULL
```

EDIT - to calculate the percentage of times each server has been in use in the last 24 hours (assuming the count of 84 times as the max it can be used in 24 hours):-

```
SELECT a.serverip, (COUNT(b.serverip) / 84) * 100 AS percentage_not_used
FROM server a
LEFT OUTER JOIN server b
ON a.serverip = b.serverip
AND b.serverip >='$ipfrom' 
AND b.serverip<='$ipto' 
AND b.time > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY a.serverip
```

Joins the table of servers against itself. First occurence of the table is used to get the serverip (whether used in the last 24 hours or not), while the 2nd is to get the number of times it has been used in the last 24 hours (the count will ignore nulls).

Comment: This cronjob run's once a day (at 23:00). does this also work's when I edit 10 minutes to 24 hour?

Comment: Should do. Not tested (no test data)

Comment: it seems not to work. I've thought up a solution myself. The software checks between 9:00 to 16:00. 16 - 9 * 60 / 5 = 84. If the PC is on for a full day (100%) there should be 84 rows. If there is any less there would be less percentage. It's not realy reliable, but there are so many computers in the range a percent more or less is not that of a disaster.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your requirement. I took it to mean the percentage of servers that have been used, while I now think you mean the percentage of time each server has been during the day. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. I want to have a percentage of the (active) uptime of each serverrange a day. That will be send to another database for future reverence.

Comment: Added a solution that should give you the percentage time that each server has been used in the last 24 hours.